# How to skip the second element in a slice?

Tags: go, slice

In this code, I have four strings in a slice but I want to skip the second one. How to do it?

**Required Result**

```
Title
Profession
Gender
```

**Code**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    data := [...]string{"Title", "Description", "Profession", "Gender"}
    for _, val := range data[1:] {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the entire slice and skip the second element.

First return value of `range` is index (starting from 0) of current element. You can use that to decide if you want to skip or not. [`continue`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Continue_statements) keyword will immediately iterate to the next element of the inner-most loop without executing the rest of the loop body for current step.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    data := [...]string{"Title", "Description", "Profession", "Gender"}
    for i, val := range data {
        if i == 1 {
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is another question regarding this code. If I want to write index numbers with it then I write `fmt.Printf("%d. %s\n", i+1, val)` but it prints the one index, skip 2 and then start from 3.

Comment: You cannot use `i` for that easily as it matches real index in slice (and you are skipping one item). Best is to define another variable and increase with each printed item but not with skipped one. See https://go.dev/play/p/vPKjClkbk7u . Same approach will also work with skipping based on e.g. `val == "Description` instead where you don't need `i` at all.

Answer (score 1):

If your slice is always the same than you can do it like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    data := [...]string{"Title", "Description", "Profession", "Gender"}
    for i, val := range data {
        if i == 1 {
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println(val)

    }
}
```

But, if you want to skip the Description no matter the slice order than you can do it like this:

```
func main() {
    data := [...]string{"Title", "Gender", "Profession", "Description"}
    for _, val := range data {
        if val == "Description" {
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println(val)

    }
}
```

In the first example you will filter by the index of the array, in the second you will filter by the actual value of the current array index.

Comment: Here is another question regarding this code. If I want to write index numbers with it then I write `fmt.Printf("%d. %s\n", i+1, val)` but it prints the one index, skip 2 and then start from 3.

Comment: ```func main() {
 data := [...]string{"Title", "Gender", "Profession", "Description"}
 indexedNumber := 1
 for i, val := range data {
  if i == 2 {
   continue
  }
  fmt.Printf("%d. %s\n", indexedNumber, val)
  indexedNumber++
 }
}```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `append` to skip like this

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    idxToSkip := 1
    data := [...]string{"Title", "Description", "Profession", "Gender"}
    for _, val := range append(data[:idxToSkip], data[idxToSkip+1:]...) {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}
```